# Optimizing for the minimum relative distance in a given situation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, systems-of-equations

I have primarily been working on this problem for quite some time now; the level of the problem is introductory calculus w/ optimization problems.

The situation is as follows:

> Ship A sails due east at $5$ km/h and sees Ship B $5$ km northeast of
>   Ship A sailing due south at $4$ km/h. At what moment will the two
>   ships be closest to one another?

And just for one's information, the answer is approximately $47$ minutes according to the solutions manual.

However, I have been getting approximately $29$ minutes from the way I have set up my equation, so I would like to inquire whether or not my method of optimization for this sort of problem is right or wrong. If so, it would really be great if you could aid me in setting up the equations properly.

**My Setup**

We have the distance, $5$ km north east. Use the **distance formula**.

$$d = \sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}$$

At the very initiation of the system (when time is $0$), Ship A is at $(0, 0).$ Have Ship A represent $(x_1, y_1).$

$$d = \sqrt{(x_2)^2 + (y_2)^2}$$

Plug in $d = 5$ km and solve for one variable.

$$5 = \sqrt{(x_2)^2 + (y_2)^2}$$
$$25 = (x_2)^2 + (y_2)^2$$
$$\sqrt{25 - (x_2)^2} = (y_2)$$

$y2$ should represent the given $y$-coordinate of Ship B. As Ship B continues sailing south at $4$ km/h, its displacement can be modeled with:

$$\mathrm{Ship\ B} = y_2 - 4x = \sqrt{25 - (x_2)^2} - 4x$$
(where $x$ is time delta)

We also know that Ship A simply has a velocity of $5$ km/h and thus can be modeled with:

$$\mathrm{Ship\ A} = 5_x$$

I then use the Pythagorean Theorem to determine the relative distance between the two, and optimize the equation for the minimal distance between the two.

$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2$$
$$c^2 = (5x)^2 + \left(\sqrt{25 - (x_2)^2} - 4x\right)^2$$
$$c = \sqrt{(5x)^2 + \left(\sqrt{25 - (x_2)^2} - 4x\right)^2}$$

I then calculate the derivative and locate wherever there is no rate of change. In this case I got around $0.49$ which only represents $29$ minutes; not $47$ minutes as the solutions manual has stated.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28%28sqrt%2825+-+%28x%29%5E2%29+-+4x%29%5E2+%2B+%285x%29%5E2%29+derivative+zeroes

If there is anything wrong with my thought process or setup of equations, please let me know. Or, if I am just proceeding with this question completely wrong, then it would be great if you would lead me on to the right path.

Comment: You correctly calculate the length $5x$ of the vector from the origin to Ship A, and the length $\sqrt{25 - (x_2)^2} - 4x$ of the vector from the origin to Ship B. But these two vectors _are not at right angles to each other_, so you cannot use the Pythagorean theorem to find the distance between the tips of the vectors. A correct solution has been posted that gives better way of modeling the distance.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of solving this. You should draw a picture of the 
situation first.

One way is to model both ships as a line.

$p_A(0) = t(5,0), p_B(0) = {5\over \sqrt{2}}(1,1)+t (0,-4)$.

It is easier to work with the square of distance.

Now compute $s(t) = \|p_B(t)-p_A(t)\|^2 = \|{5\over \sqrt{2}}(1,1) +t(-5,-4) \|^2=
({5\over \sqrt{2}}-5t)^2 + ({5\over \sqrt{2}}-4t)^2 $.

Now differentiate, set it equal to zero and solve for $t$.

You will get $t = {45 \over 41 \sqrt{2}}$. Remember to convert to minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of looking at problems like this. Consider everything from the point of view of a passenger sitting in a deck chair on Ship A watching the world pass by.

The passenger, sitting in the chair, sees Ship A as a stationary platform--Ship A is the origin of the passenger's coordinate system, and Ship A never moves away from the origin--while the ocean passes by Ship A at a rate of $5$ km/h to the west. 
Ship B is initially at the point 
$\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}2 5, \frac{\sqrt 2}2 5\right),$ that is, 
$\frac{\sqrt 2}2 5$ km north and $\frac{\sqrt 2}2 5$ km east of Ship A.
After one hour, Ship B will have moved $5$ km west due to being carried in that direction by the ocean, and $4$ km south due to its own motion relative to the water, to reach the point 
$\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}2 5 - 5, \frac{\sqrt 2}2 5 - 4\right).$

In other words, Ship B moves along a line $\ell$ of slope $\frac45$ through
$\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}2 5, \frac{\sqrt 2}2 5\right)$
at a speed of $\sqrt{5^2 + 4^2}$ km/h in the direction toward negative values of both coordinates.
Find the point on that line that is closest to the origin.
(Hint: the line from the origin is perpendicular to $\ell$ at that point, so you are looking for a point that is on the line $y=-\frac54x$ as well as
on the line $\ell$).
Find the distance (in km) between that point and the starting point
$\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}2 5, \frac{\sqrt 2}2 5\right),$
and divide that distance by the speed
$\sqrt{5^2 + 4^2}$ km/h
in order to find the number of hours taken to reach that point.
Then multiply by $60$ in order to find the answer in minutes.