# Closest approach of two airplanes with intersecting paths on a 2D plane

Tags: geometry, vectors

I'm writing a program that has to find the closest approach of two airplanes.

The problem could be brute-forced, but that would be a waste of opportunity to solve it in an elegant way. I was unable to do it even after resarching the problem online - your help is much appreciated.

**Assumptions:**

- There are two airplanes in a 2D coordinate plane.
- Each airplane is defined by its starting position and vector (direction and velocity)
- Starting positions of airplane #1 and airplane #2 are defined by random, non-negative coordinates: $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ respectively.
- Airplane #1 has a random direction $(θ_1)$ defined by angle relative to north (or the y axis): $<0;360)$
- Airplane #2 has a random direction $(θ_2)$ such that **it crosses the future path of airplane #1**
- The velocities of airplanes $(ρ_1, ρ_2)$ are random numbers: $<1;2>$.
- Just to clarify: the velocities will almost always be different numbers - they don't have to be equal.

## **Find coordinates of airplanes at the moment of closest approach**

i.e. at the moment in time when airplanes are closest to each other.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What "brute force" approaches have you considered and why did you dismiss them? (To quote a very great physicist, "elegance is for shoemakers and tailors".)

Comment: These questions and their answers seem related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192619/optimizing-for-the-minimum-relative-distance-in-a-given-situation, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775476/shortest-distance-between-two-objects-moving-along-two-lines, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149337/closest-approach-intuition

Comment: The following is a slightly different problem but the technique can apply here also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2994568/calculating-the-time-at-which-2-airplanes-will-be-a-specific-distance-apart-from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the vector displacement between the planes is given by ...
$$  \vec d =(d_x+v_xt,d_y+v_y t )    $$

where $d_x = x_2-x_1$ ,  $d_y = y_2-y_1$

$v_x = \rho_2 \sin(\theta_2)  - \rho_1 \sin(\theta_1) $

$v_y = \rho_2 \cos(\theta_2)  - \rho_1 \cos(\theta_1) $

the magnitude of $\vec d $ is minimized when

$$ t = -\frac{d_x v_x + d_y v_y}{v_x^2 + v_y^2} $$